# Graph theory and combinatorics problem

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

There are 20 people at a party and each one of them is friends with at least 10 of the people. They all sit at a round table. Prove that there is a way to place the people on the table, so that each one is friends with the person on his right and with the person on his left.

I am not sure if I understand this problem. Does it mean that each person must not know only one person? If that is the case, then we have a problem when n is odd. But then is it required that everyone must not know one person?

Can anyone clarify this question and give a hint as to how to prove it?

Comment: Not sure I can give a hint, but I can at least clarify the question. What they mean is that, if you pick any two of the guests, everyone else knows at least one of those two.

Comment: @Fargle I'm not sure how that clarifies anything. I mean, your explanation is perfectly clear, but it seems just as clear in the original. It's hard for me to understand how the OP managed to misunderstand it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem tells us that for each pair of guests, a person at the dinner knows at least one of them. If you turn it into graph then it means that for any pair of two vertices, each of the remaining ones is adjacent to at least one of the two vertices in the pair.

On the other side the problem reduces to finding a Hamiltonian cycle in the graph. Such a cycle exists because of the Ore's Theorem.

Comment: More simply, it tells us that for each guest, there is at most one guest he doesn't know; i.e., the complement has maximum degree at most one. Ore's theorem seems like overkill.

Comment: @user1944 Yeah, pretty much. You can use bof's arguement from above. In fact that theorem is called Dirac's Theorem and it's a special case of the Ore's Theorem.